# mysql SUBSTRING() and LOCATE()

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql's [`SUBSTRING()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) function and [`LOCATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) to capture "n" characters before and after some string.

For example, using the string "apple". When I query it works fine except if the string "apple" is towards the beginning of the string since 10 characters before may be non-existent:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f41f8d/5

```
CREATE TABLE demo (name varchar(1000));
INSERT INTO demo (name) VALUES 
    ("An apple a day keeps the doctor away"), 
    ("A doctor a day keeps the apple away from the doctor");

SELECT SUBSTRING(
  `name`,
  LOCATE("apple",`name`) - 10, /* from 10 characters before 'string'*/
  (25) /* to 10 characters after the 5 strlen string (so 10 + 5 + 10) */
)
FROM demo
WHERE name like '%apple%'
```

**Results**

```
| r away                    |
| keeps the apple away from |
```

The second results is as expected, but the first - I would like it to start at the beginning of the string until 10 characters after "apple".

What's wrong with my query or how can I fix it? I'm also queries millions of rows so I assume a sub-query to check if it's position is less than "string"'s length isn't performant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
  `name`,
  GREATEST(LOCATE("apple",`name`) - 10, 1), /* from 10 characters before 'string'*/
  LEAST(25, LENGTH(name) - GREATEST(LOCATE("apple",`name`) - 10, 1)) /* to 10 characters after the 5 strlen string (so 10 + 5 + 10) */
)
FROM demo
WHERE name like '%apple%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name,
                 GREATEST(1, LOCATE('apple', name) - 10),
                 15 + LEAST(LOCATE('apple', name), 10)
                )
FROM demo
WHERE name like '%apple%'
```

Comment: Should it be `GREATEST(1` instead of `0`? Doesn't work with zero and docs say `the position of the first character in the string from which the substring is to be extracted is reckoned as 1`